# Check for particular sequence in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I want to look for a particular sequence occurrences in database.
Example: Consider have following table:

[image]

Consider I want to check if table has following sequence or not : **555 222 444**.
I want to display where sequence is not matching as:

[image]

Hoe can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions (Added in Sqlite 3.25 so the following needs that or a newer version) make peeking at the next row easy:

Create and populate a sample table (Posting an *image* of your data is really not useful; text with either INSERT statements or CSV is best):

```
CREATE TABLE seq(num INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value INTEGER);
INSERT INTO seq VALUES (1, 111), (2, 555), (3, 222), (4, 444), (5, 333)
                     , (6, 111), (7, 555), (8, 222), (9, 111), (10, 333)
                     , (11, 555), (12, 444), (13, 111), (14, 333), (15, 444);
```

And the query:

```
WITH leads AS (SELECT num, value
                    , lead(value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY num) AS next1
                    , lead(value, 2) OVER (ORDER BY num) AS next2
               FROM seq)
SELECT CASE WHEN next1 = 222 AND next2 = 444 THEN 'MATCH' ELSE 'FAIL' END AS result
     , num AS start
     , CASE WHEN next1 = 222 AND next2 = 444 THEN num + 2 ELSE num + 1 END AS "end"
FROM leads
WHERE value = 555
ORDER BY num;
```

produces

```
result      start       end       
----------  ----------  ----------
MATCH       2           4         
FAIL        7           8         
FAIL        11          12
```

(All of the above assumes you're using the `num` column to determine ordering)